# Interval partitioning with restrictions: NP-complete or efficiently solvable?

Tags: ds.algorithms, np-hardness, max-flow-min-cut, greedy-algorithms

The interval partitioning problem can be solved [efficiently using a greedy algorithm](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/kleinberg-tardos/pearson/04GreedyAlgorithms-2x2.pdf). However, adding restrictions on the interval assignment to the problem results in a problem that appears harder. Here's my problem formulation:

- There are $n$ rooms. We want to hold $m$ events in these rooms. These events have fixed (given as input) starting times $s_1,\dots,s_m$ and finishing times $f_1,\dots,f_m$.
- Each event must be held in exactly one room, and two events cannot be held in the same room at the same time.
- Certain events can be held in only certain rooms. This is given as an input as an $n$ by $m$ matrix of booleans.
- We want to figure out whether all events can be held in these rooms.

It seems to me that a greedy algorithm can't solve this. Additionally, since bipartite matching is a special case of this problem (when all events are held at the same time), I have attempted to transform this "interval partitioning with restrictions" problem into a maximum flow problem, with no success. I have also considered trying to prove that this problem is NP-complete, but I don't know where to start.

Could anybody help me either find an efficient algorithm for this or prove that it is NP-complete?

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi I don't see how the reduction from the [3-partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem) to this problem could be possible. That problem deals with sums of integers, but my problem doesn't have any summing. Could you give me some directions?

Comment: sorry, I read the question too quickly and didn't notice the "fixed starting time"; there is no direct/quick reduction to 3-PARTITION ! ... I'll think if there is a quick reduction to another problem later.

Comment: @NealYoung: of course, forget my quick fart-like comment (I'll delete it ;-). Lacker's reduction is elegant and correct (so I didn't spend more time on the problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a reduction from 3SAT. For each of your 3SAT variables $x_0$, imagine there is one event $x_0$ and two rooms called "Room $x_0$ is true" and "Room $x_0$ is false". The event $x_0$ has to be in one of those two rooms. Whichever statement is true, that's the room we *don't* use. And it is going to take all day. So the only rooms generally available for other events are the rooms named with a true statement.

Now let's say you want to add a condition - $x_0$ OR $x_1$ OR NOT $x_2$. Make that into an event that's just one nanosecond long, at a random time so it doesn't conflict with the other condition-events. And it has to be held in one of "Room $x_0$ is true", "Room $x_1$ is true", or "Room $x_2$ is false".

Now solving your event assignment problem lets you solve an arbitrary 3SAT problem.

Comment: Yes. That does, in fact, work, huh. I somehow didn't consider reducing directly from 3-SAT. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer starts by "Here's a reduction to 3SAT", but you mean a reduction *from* 3SAT, right?

Comment: I guess so - I always get the two confused. I edited the answer. It's the direction that proves this scheduling problem is hard :P